# Successive versions of packages accumulating in the ~/.emacs.d/elpa folder

Tags: package

I noticed that successive versions of packages have been accumulating in my ~/.emacs.d/elpa folder, like so:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 joon users 4,0K 20 avril 15:49 auto-complete-20150408.1132
drwxr-xr-x   3 joon users 4,0K 16 juin  17:14 auto-complete-20150615.34
drwxr-xr-x   3 joon users 4,0K  1 juil. 18:00 auto-complete-20150618.1949
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K 31 mai   21:53 avy-20150530.111
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K  4 juin  16:42 avy-20150603.919
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K 12 juin  17:07 avy-20150608.404
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K 16 juin  17:14 avy-20150615.1048
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K  1 juil. 18:00 avy-20150701.532
drwxr-xr-x   2 joon users 4,0K  7 juil. 19:53 avy-20150707.811
```

Is this normal? Is there a quick way to get rid of old versions ?

Comment: Do you get any error or warning in a buffer when upgrading a package? Try this out: (1) Delete the latest version of `avy` from your `elpa` dir (2) Restart emacs (3) `M-x package-list-packages` (4) Hit `U` and then `x` (5) You should will be asked to delete older versions after the latest versions are installed (6) **Agree** to the deletion.

Comment: @kaushalmodi You can directly delete old versions, there's no need to remove the newest first.

Comment: @lunaryorn If he doesn't delete the latest version, then the package manager will not prompt to upgrade (and then delete the older versions). I asked him to delete the latest version for him to test the upgrade+deletion process.

Comment: I presumed you had suggested this as the way to delete obsolete versions, but I see that I've been mistaken.  I'm sorry, please excuse the confusion.

Comment: I tried what @kaushalmodi suggested. It did delete old versions of the package I had manually deleted, but it did not prompt me for confirmation. I had to check the *Messages* buffer to see that they had been deleted. I'm wondering whether this has something to do with my emacs version which is 25 since recently, and/or the fact that I use my .emacs.d folder synced betweed different machines, which may have slightly different versions of emacs (but all >= 25)...

Answer (score 3):

That is unusual at least.  Normally package.el asks you whether to delete old versions after upgrade, meaning that you'd have made a conscious decision to keep them.

Anyway, you can remove old versions explicitly with `M-x list-packages`, then `~` to mar obsolete packages for deletion and eventually `x` to perform this action.  That should delete all old versions of your installed packages.